# Python daemon status is unknown

Tags: python, daemon, daemons, python-daemon, launch-daemon

I have created a python daemon by a [Tutorial](http://www.gavinj.net/2012/06/building-python-daemon-process.html) and it is running just as tutorial example has. But there are problems:

The output of `service --status-all` says:

> [ ? ]  testdaemon

Can anyone help me to find out what those errors and warnings are or fix the status of my daemon so that it'll be this:

> [ + ]  testdaemon

Comment: _"as you see there are errors on logfile that I cant see their description:"_ Have you simply _look_ at the sources of your daemon? The function `run` _only_ logs error,warning,info & debug message every 10 seconds. For demonstration purpose, I assume...